# Contact from 7 dropdown mandatory functionality is not working in Google chrome

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

```
[select* refferal-from "Google " "Recommendation" "Checkatrade" "Social Media" "Returning customer" "Seen us on the road" "Advert" "Prefer not to say"]
```

The above code, I am using in my site`s contact form 7 to make to make this field mandatory but this is not supporting in google chrome and working great in Mozilla Firefox.

Any idea?, Please help..... :-(

Comment: It's working fine in my google chrome?

Comment: testing here : https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Comment: @Stender Ah... Thanks now it`s working - After using first_as_label :-)